# Github Desktop - Not showing changes

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

Basically I changed a few files in Notepad++ but it wont show up in Github for Windows.

[image: gif]

I have tried reinstalling, Restarting pc and constantly re-cloning into different parts on my pc.

Nothing seems to do anything

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check in command line if you have a `.gitignore` rule that ignores those changes

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git check-ignore -v -- afile
```

It can be a local `.gitignore`, or a global one.

The other possibility is if you are in a [detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).
Check the output of `git branch`.

Finally, check again **[how to work with a local repo with GitHub Desktop](https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing-to-projects/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/)**: the comments below show that:

```
git status
git add . 
git commit -m "add changes"
```

All this work as expected from command line.

The [OP Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567815/shiny) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278591/github-desktop-not-showing-changes/38278620?noredirect=1#comment63976799_38278620):

> Seems like a bug I need to report to Github, But basically **I set my username of my PC to "`{Shiny}`" and it seems if "`{}`" is in the path it glitches it out**.

That is why I always recommend starting with simpler path: `C:\git\myrepo`, just to validate that it works there.

Comment: I dont have any .gitignore at all

Comment: @Shiny It does not matter: execute that command anyway, it can be a global one.

Comment: ok, I did: git check-ignore -v -- README.md nothing was returned.

Comment: @Shiny Make sure to use the latest git (https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.9.0.windows.1/PortableGit-2.9.0-64-bit.7z.exe for Windows for instance)

Comment: @Shiny Do you have at least one commit in your current repo? git log returns anything?

Comment: Yes I have 106 xD No idea where the Git Log is.

Comment: @Shiny All you need to do is typing `git log`.

Comment: @Shiny that is your problem right there. What `git branch` returns?

Comment: master as usual "*master" to be exact

Comment: But `git log` returns nothing? Strange. What does `git remote -v` returns?

Comment: git log returns stuff but nothing to do with what ive done only old commits

Comment: it returns: origin  https://github.com/ShinyMK/JKSMK.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ShinyMK/JKSMK.git (push)

Comment: @Shiny Ok. What `git status` returns?

Comment: On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   README.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        README - Copy.md

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

Comment: It also seems to be constantly doing this blue loading thing that u see in the .gif. not sure if its normal to be constantly doing that

Comment: @Shiny So in command line, the status is coherent: a `git diff` should show you the diff in progress, a `git add` and `git commit` should allow you to record those changes?

Comment: The difference is being shown with git diff yes. Gonna try the other 2 commands now

Comment: @Shiny `git add .` (see the space dot there) and `git commit -m "Add changes"`

Comment: tried using the other 2 commands but I have no idea how it would work. But it is detecting the modified files - EDIT: Just saw ur comment. That worked. Github for Desktop (GUI) still doesnt seem to be working.

Comment: @Shiny That seems to be a usage issue with GitHub for Desktop, then. Try and see if you can follow https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/

Comment: @Shiny Also, from command line, you can do a `git push`. That will update the remote repo with your changes.

Comment: The repository using that way seems to add fine. But again doesnt seem to fix the issue :/

Comment: @Shiny Yes, try again to clone that repo with GitHub Desktop in a new folder, and try again to modify files in that local folder, to see if GitHub Desktop picks up the changes.

Comment: Making changes from Git Bash works fine using the commands u have provided me. But again still it doesnt show changed files in the GUI itself

Comment: @Shiny Yes, hence the suggestion to try again in a new local folder created by GitHub Desktop when cloning a remote repo, as in https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/cloning-a-repository-from-github-desktop/

Comment: Yes I tried doing that already in Desktop, Documents (GitHub Folder), Documents (Projects Folder). Still not working

Comment: @Shiny `GitHub Desktop` is the name of the GitHub GUI. It has nothing to with the local folder you chose to clone your repo to. Try cloning in a simple path (`C:\git\myrepo`), then follow https://help.github.com/desktop/guides/contributing/adding-a-repository-from-your-local-computer-to-github-desktop/

Comment: Oh wow, Now I know why its not working, Seems like a bug I need to report to Github, But basically I set my username of my PC to "{Shiny}" and it seems if "{}" is in the path it glitches it out xD

Comment: @Shiny Well done, and well spotted! I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score -3):

save file in vscode  , then try to see the changes in the github desktop , there u might be able to the changes . Also make  sure to reinstall git and git hub if the problem still persists .